# Can Ubuntu Unattended Upgrades be configured to download only?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt

I'd like to configure Ubuntu unattended-upgrades package to only download updates but not apply them. Is this possible? I'm not seeing a way to do it on this [page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticSecurityUpdates) but they show something using *cron* that could probably be adapted to do it. Just wondering if the U.U. package does it somehow instead of reinventing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to:

1. Configure **/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic** to --download-only, adding a line:

> APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "1";
> APT::Periodic::Download-Upgradeable-Packages "1";

NOTE: You can look to other option on file /usr/lib/apt/apt.systemd.daily (ubuntu 20.04)

2. Configure **/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades to disable unattended-upgrade, adding a line

> APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "0";

However, I strongly recommend to, at least, unable automatic security updates, which means enabling unattended-upgrades only for security updates.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give the `...10periodic` a try.